# Unable to install Storm using PIP

Tags: python, pip

Unable to install storm receiving the following error while doing so.

Installed pip version as follows:

pip 19.2.3

`pip install storm`

````
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a7/4c/e5dbc818c432cd80d2e1aa1576f911eda49a3c206c6697db4070f402cda9/storm-0.20.tar.bz2
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/lk/wrg280_17c78l9kysqx26pdc0000gp/T/pip-install-so_kwd18/storm/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/lk/wrg280_17c78l9kysqx26pdc0000gp/T/pip-install-so_kwd18/storm/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: /private/var/folders/lk/wrg280_17c78l9kysqx26pdc0000gp/T/pip-install-so_kwd18/storm/
    Complete output (8 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/lk/wrg280_17c78l9kysqx26pdc0000gp/T/pip-install-so_kwd18/storm/setup.py", line 5, in <module>
        import ez_setup
      File "/private/var/folders/lk/wrg280_17c78l9kysqx26pdc0000gp/T/pip-install-so_kwd18/storm/ez_setup.py", line 106
        except pkg_resources.VersionConflict, e:
                                            ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.```
````

When trying to install `strom` i am receiving the above error.

Answer (score 3):

The package `storm` for Python has not been maintained. The latest version 0.20 is released at 2013. The project doesn't support Python 3 at all.

Answer (score -2):

It's in package, syntax error. You need to change comma(this symbol ' , ') in said line:

> File
>   "/private/var/folders/lk/wrg280_17c78l9kysqx26pdc0000gp/T/pip-install-so_kwd18/storm/ez_setup.py",
>   line 106

```
except pkg_resources.VersionConflict, e:
```

to 'as', it should look like:

```
except pkg_resources.VersionConflict as e:  # in package there is ','
```

But if you are just starting project, DO NOT use storm, as it's last update was nearly 7 years ago and it's not clear if it's compatible with python 3. 
I don't know what you are using it for but search for something with constant support. If you are not sure which package is getting support search for last realease date on:
[PyPi library](https://pypi.org/project/storm/)

Answer (score -3):

Installing directly from shell / terminal may help rather then to do it in program.

Comment: You need to add the package containing the executable pg_config.